# wkhtmltopdf add white space between content on every page

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating a PDF and it will create a white space between content.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4mo5.png)

When I output the same content just in HTML it will not, so I don't think it's the HTML or CSS; however, something on generating a PDF is creating that small gap, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am hoping it's just a wkhtmltopdf setting, but I have been through all of them.

I am setting them in PHP like this:

```
return [
        'page-size' => 'A4',
        'page-height' => $height,
        'page-width' => $width,
        'dpi' => 96,
        'margin-left' => 0,
        'margin-right' => 0,
        'margin-top' => 0,
        'margin-bottom' => 0,
        'disable-smart-shrinking' => true,
        'load-media-error-handling' => 'abort'
    ];
```

I have added the `page-size` in an attempt to solve it, but it did not work.